# Need to login in to remote website using c#

Tags: c#, iframe

I am trying to log in to a remote website via a login form so I can access a sub page via iFrame so I have to pass the validation to set a cookie or a session so I can get to the sub page with the iFrame Maybe there is a better way to do this I am not 100% sure if anyone has any suggestions please let me know. I am getting access denied error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitEstimoteLogin() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var ifr = document.getElementById("iFrameLogin");

                var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
                var theForm = ifrDoc.forms[0];
                var username = theform.getElementById("username");
                username.value = "email";
                var password = theform.getElementById("password");
                password.value = "password";
                var sbutton = thefrom.getElementById("");
        }, 5000);
}
</script>
        <iframe id="iFrameLogin" src="http://cloud.estimote.com" onload="submitEstimoteLogin();"  ></iframe>
```

I have also tried it via code behind I am getting a 404 error:

```
public String GetWebContent(String username, String password)
    {
        String urlSignin = "https://cloud.estimote.com/";
        String urlLogin = "https://cloud.estimote.com/";
        Uri uriSignin = new Uri(urlSignin);
        Uri uriLogin = new Uri(urlLogin);
        Hashtable formData = new Hashtable();
        formData.Add("username", new Hashtable());
        formData.Add("password", new Hashtable());
        ((Hashtable)formData["username"])["value"] = username;
        ((Hashtable)formData["password"])["value"] = password;
        String postData = "";
        foreach (string name in formData.Keys)
        {
            postData += "&" + name + "=" + ((Hashtable)formData[name])["value"];
        }
        postData = postData.Substring(1);
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        HttpWebRequest webReq;
        HttpWebResponse webResp;
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        String responseString = "";
        try
        {
            webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlSignin);
            webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

            for (int i = 0; i < webResp.Headers.Count; i++)
            {
                string name = webResp.Headers.GetKey(i);
                if (name != "Set-Cookie")
                    continue;
                string value = webResp.Headers.Get(i);
                foreach (var singleCookie in value.Split(','))
                {
                    Match match = Regex.Match(singleCookie, "(.+?)=(.+?);");
                    if (match.Captures.Count == 0)
                        continue;
                    webResp.Cookies.Add(
                        new Cookie(
                            match.Groups[1].ToString(),
                            match.Groups[2].ToString(),
                            "/",
                            webReq.Host.Split(':')[0]));
                }
            }
            cookies.Add(webResp.Cookies);
            string sessionCookie = webResp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
            responseString = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            string respCookie = sessionCookie.Substring(0, sessionCookie.IndexOf(';'));
            char[] separator = { '=' };
            string[] cookieValues = respCookie.Split(separator);
            string part1 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookieValues[1]);
            cookies.Add(new Cookie(cookieValues[0], part1 , "/", "cloud.estimote.com"));
            webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlLogin);
            webReq.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            webReq.Referer = urlSignin;
            webReq.KeepAlive = true;
            webReq.Method = "POST";
            webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
            webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            webReq.CookieContainer = cookies;
            webReq.Timeout = 30000;
            webReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;
            webReq.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            webReq.GetRequestStream().Close();
            webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
            responseString = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            webResp.Close();
            return responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I assumed my request was clear, I am trying to log in to a website via c# to create a session or a cookie to access a sub page.

Comment: I have edited it to ask maybe there is a better way of doing this.